# GTA V Online Business

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I keep getting texts from Lester and others to buy an arcade, nightclub, etc. What are all these businesses and how do they work? They all seem really expensive to buy, so I don't want to blow all my money on one of them and then find out its useless. I only play 1-2 hours a night so I feel like its a big investment.

I've read some info online, but I'm not sure if people are changing the terminology and its the same thing, or they are talking about different things. It would be clearer I suppose if they ever mentioned HOW to buy any of these businesses - then I would know which is which. The other issue is that most of the info is pre-casino.

Do I pick one? Or can I do all of them at the same time? If I can do them all at the same time - which order should I buy them in to make it easiest to get them all?

So far I've seen mentions of:

- Arena Wars
- Arcade - needed for casino heist?
- Apartment - needed to Setup Heists. Also for Living the Dream achievement.
- Casino Luxury Penthouse - also needed to setup Casino Heist? Can it be used for other heists?
- Nightclub
- MotorCycle Gangs
- Bunker
- Hangar
- Garage - store cars! Needed for Living the Dream achievement. Does it do anything else?
- Vehicle Warehouse
- Warehouse - not sure if this is the same as the vehicle warehouse
- CEO
- Big Boat thingy
- Big Truck HQ thingy
- Facility

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, firstly you don't **HAVE** to get anything here, but I'll explain what everything does and what would be good early on. You can buy a lot of stuff here from Foreclosures, but others will be on Warstock, that ship website (forgot the name) and the Diamond Casino Website.

- Arena War Garage is near useless. It only allows you to modify Arena War cars to be used in that mode or in freeroam. The cars are mediocre and Arena War itself is more barren than the Blaine County deserts.
- Arcade is good in two cases;1) If you want to do the casino heist, which I've heard is really good, you need it. 2) It has the ability, with proper upgrades, to run other businesses such as, MC Businesses, Bunker and the Nightclub. It can also source CEO Crates, Vehicle Cargo and Hangar Crates. All these things require the proper businesses and also can be done at said businesses but it is more for convenience sake.
- To run a heist you need a luxury apartment, so minimum 200k. Nothing higher than that.
- Casino Penthouse lets you do missions specific to the Diamond Casino update. It doesn't help with the heist.
- Nightclub is a vital money-making building **WHEN** you have other properties, including MC Businesses, Ceo Crates and the Bunker.
- MC Clubhouses lets you buy MC Businesses, they make money and you sell the product in a lobby. Max sales are 420k **MINUS** high demand bonus (more money the more players).
- Bunker is very similar to a MC Business, but with more storage, the ability to hold a MOC and to perform research. Similarly crucial to MC Businesses for making dough.
- Hangar is a meh business, with 4 players you can make huge bucks but without that it takes a while to fill it up with crates.
- Don't buy garages, buy luxury apartments if you need more car space, they come with 10 spaces.
- Vehicle Warehouse is a extremely good solo business, if you are good you can make 80k in the span of 10 mins, with another 15min cooldown for your next sell.
- CEO Warehouses take a while to fill, but oh god if you get a 2x money event on them you can make millions. You can have up to 5 of them, only buy the large ones.
- CEO Office is required to get the CEO Warehouse and Vehicle Warehouse. You can also register as VIP when below 50k.
- Don't. Buy. A. Yacht. It's 10 mil and really you only get free RPG ammo from it.
- Idk if you are talking about the MOC or Terrorbyte, but I'll run through them both. The MOC is stored in the Bunker, has turrets in it and carried by a separate semi-truck. It can do MOC Missions. The Terrorbyte is stored in the Nightclub, can store and upgrade the Oppressor MK. 2 and can allow you to source items for your other businesses from it. You can also do Client Jobs from it.
- The Facility lets you run the doomsday heist, unless you are willing to throw up more for the Orbital Cannon, that's it really.

So, you may be wondering what order to get these in, lemme run down.

- MC Businesses and Clubhouse for money making.
- CEO Office
- Vehicle Warehouse
- Bunker
- Nightclub
- Arcade (if you are lazy or want to do Casino Heist)
- CEO Crates
- Hangar
- Facility
- MOC/Terrorbyte/Avenger, whatever you prefer
  After that I think the order is non-necessary, but make sure all your businesses are fully upgraded (NOT COSMETIC-WISE) before getting other stuff.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Nice answer just some extra i know. If you buy the hangar in Fort Zancudo you can go in without getting a wanted level until you start shooting. For the facility, you have to own it if you want the Doomsday special vehicles, you can only store some of them in the facility. Same with vehicle warehouse, you can only store special import/export vehicles there.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a difference between buying a business and running it? In story mode you can buy businesses but they do almost nothing except for a couple of occasional side missions. I guess I'll spend some of this free $2M Rockstar handed out this month to find out lol.

Comment: Yeah, huge in online businesses are, they ain't passive, and you gotta actually go out in a public lobby to sell, which puts you at risk. But you can make millions if you pull it off consistently.